# How to modify azure build pipeline yml file after upgrading my angular project from v9 to 10

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, angular10

I am new to azure build pipeline yml file. I have recently upgraded my angular application from v9 to v10.
I want to update my azure devops build pipeline yml file. Here is my snippet of azure pipeline yml. Is this the right way? Because I dont want this to be installed everytime. How to add a condition to this task?

```
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'NPM install angular-cli'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      workingDir: 'Src/Proj'          
      customCommand: 'install -g @angular/cli@10.1.6'
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'NPM install'
    inputs:
      command: 'install'
      workingDir: 'Src/Proj'
    condition: eq(variables['npmCacheRestored'],False)
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'NPM run lint:ci'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      workingDir: 'Src/Proj'
      customCommand: 'run lint:ci'
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'NPM run test:ci'
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      workingDir: 'Src/Proj'
      customCommand: 'run test:ci'
```

Answer (score 0):

All is fine here in terms of building Angular app. If you want to cache your npm modules you can add this:

```yaml
      - task: Cache@2
        inputs:
          key: 'node_modules  | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
          restoreKeys: |
            node_modules  | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json
          path: node_modules
          cacheHitVar: NODE_MODULES_RESTORED
        displayName: Cache node_modules

      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: 'Front End NPM install'
        inputs:
          command: 'install'
        condition: ne(variables.NODE_MODULES_RESTORED, 'true')
```

You may also consider using `npm ci` like it is in [documentation's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm) but testing both approaches I got better result with above configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Beside using [Cache task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#conditioning-on-cache-restoration) in your pipeline. If you find it hard to use.  You can also try creating a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops), and run your pipeline on this self-hosted agent.

Then you can add [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) step in your pipeline and set the `clean` attribute to false(default is true if not specified). So that the installed dependencies in the source folder on your local agent will not be cleaned for next build. And you can disable the install task for the next run.

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: false
```